# Sage Payroll 50 - NI Deduction DB tables

Tags: reporting, sage-erp

I am attempting to locate the tables in Sage Payroll 50 related to NI deduction amounts. I have located the following tables presently to put a number of reports together these include.

```
select * from SGTBL_COMPANY
select * from SGTBL_EMPLOYEEDETAILS
select * from SGTBL_EMPLOYEEHISTORY
select * from SGTBL_EMPLOYEEPAYMENT
select * from SGTBL_EMPLOYEEPERSONAL
select * from SGTBL_PAYMENTHISTORY
select * from SGTBL_PENSIONHISTORY
```

The following two tables I believed would hold this information related to NI Calculations

```
select * from SGTBL_EMPLOYEEDEDUCTIONS
select * from SGTBL_NICODEHISTORY
```

However neither appear to hold the related information that match to the employee record. Is this information held within a particular table, or calculated in a different manner. If anyone has experience with data extracts from Sage for reporting on numbers per employee for a given period.